# Surrogate ID for posts, is there an alternative field in the posts table?

Tags: posts, database, api, id

I am copying some content between another CMS and Wordpress.
I need to keep track of the original Id because I might have to update the copied content in the future. The old CMS will still be used for some time since users still need to learn WP.

I am currently using metafields for this, but this obliges me to make updates to two different tables in the database (the posts and the meta). I would rather prefer to just update once using some alternative field in the post table.

For the amount of articles I have to copy the impact is not neglectable at ll.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you importing those posts. You can use `wp_insert_post()` with `import_id`:

```
$postToBeInserted = array(
    'post_title'    => 'Your Post Title',
    'post_content'  => 'Your post content...',
    'import_id'     => 154
);

wp_insert_post($postToBeInserted);
```

If there is no post with the specified `import_id` the post will have that `ID`. That way you won't have to deal with meta fields and all migrated posts will have the same `ID` as in the previous CMS. Although there is a drawback because it can lead to potential collisions if you continue to post new posts in the old CMS.